# How to get the attribute of some list element when we have only the title of the element?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I need to get "data-key" value of the element (with title "Some name") that is specified in the tag "tr". Method element.getAttribute(attributeName) returns null. How can I do this using Selenium WD + Java?

```
<tr data-key="20"><td>Some name</td>...
```

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    driver.navigate().to(some url);
    WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text() = 'Some name']"));
    String val = elem.getAttribute("data-key");
    System.out.print(val);
}
```

returns null

Comment: Please include the source code which you are trying, and its giving null value. So we can suggest other relevant source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<tr>` tag is parent element of the element with text "Some name". You can use `xpath` parent `..` or `parent::` to locate it

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text() = 'Some name']/.."));
// or By.xpath("//*[text() = 'Some name']/parent::tr");
element.getAttribute("data-key");
```